# ASP.NET MVC Virtual Action Results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an open source ASP.NET MVC 5 application, that I am trying to make as configurable and extendable as possible.

It has a set of core controllers, services etc... And I have made them all Partial classes so people can easily extend those.

I am now thinking about making all the ActionResults in the controllers virtual, to allow users to override them if they want to include custom code and leave the core method in place.

If I do this, would a user be able to override a single ActionResult on a controller or would they have to override all of them?

Comment: This really depends on what is added *new*. If a user override add something new to an action, the other actions may not change or they will need to be changed to sustain that change added.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using virtual methods, like

```
public virtual void DoSomething(){}
```

then they can override just that one method and leave the rest, since we're not dealing with an abstract class.

Also, are you talking about overriding the controller's actions? ActionResult is the return type for an action and that's extensible already.